# Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc(), 4 bytes inside a block of size 16 alloc'd

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, valgrind

I've written a program using C++. It runs fine until the end, where it vomits: *** Error in `./xwd': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000017fd774 ***

My first thought was that I was doing something wrong in the destructor, but as the relevant class has no destructor as it doesn't use "new", this was a little confusing to me. This led me to use valgrind for the first time, but that hasn't been terribly illuminating.

Valgrind gives the following complaint:

```
2 errors in context 1 of 1:
==14245== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==14245==    at 0x4C2D2E0: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14245==    by 0x407335: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long) (new_allocator.h:110)
==14245==    by 0x406429: __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::deallocate(std::allocator<int>&, int*, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:185)
==14245==    by 0x404C07: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate(int*, unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:178)
==14245==    by 0x404796: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) (vector.tcc:394)
==14245==    by 0x402C21: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_vector.h:925)
==14245==    by 0x40186C: Lexicon::Lexicon(char const*, unsigned int) (Lexicon.cpp:36)
==14245==    by 0x40B58A: main (xwd.cpp:20)
==14245==  Address 0x5a65114 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 16 alloc'd
==14245==    at 0x4C2C100: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14245==    by 0x40809D: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==14245==    by 0x4072B3: __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::allocate(std::allocator<int>&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:182)
==14245==    by 0x4061CF: std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:170)
==14245==    by 0x404684: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) (vector.tcc:353)
==14245==    by 0x402C21: std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) (stl_vector.h:925)
==14245==    by 0x40186C: Lexicon::Lexicon(char const*, unsigned int) (Lexicon.cpp:36)
==14245==    by 0x40B58A: main (xwd.cpp:20)
==14245== 
==14245== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

This points to Lexicon.cpp (http://pastebin.com/Me4AcwXx) ,line 36, which is the second-to-last line of the following code sample:

```
for(unsigned int letter = 0; letter < next.length(); letter++){    
    assert(0<=pattern.length()&&pattern.length()<=index_vectors.size());
    assert(0<=letter && letter<=index_vectors[pattern.length()].size());
    assert(0<=pattern[letter]-'A' && pattern[letter]-'A'<=index_vectors[pattern.length()][letter].size());
  index_vectors[next.length()][letter][next[letter]-'A'].push_back(word_list_index);
  full_letter_vectors[next.length()].push_back(word_list_index);   }
```

Here, `word_list_index` is simply an int. What's wrong with this picture? Am I doing something heinous? It all looks pretty normal to me.

Comment: You need to post a full reproducing example. The only thing that's obvious about that code is a bunch of usages of indices that could be out of range.

Comment: Valgrind is calling out `Lexicon::Lexicon(char const*, unsigned int)`.  Could you show the code for that?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have out of bound access in `index_vectors[next.length()][letter][next[letter]-'A']` ?

Comment: Are you sure "next[letter] - 'A'" can't produce negative indices? That might cause weird results

Comment: There's so much that can go wrong on that second line of code! (1) `index_vectors` may have fewer than `next.length()+1` elements (2) element at `next.length()` may have fewer than `letter+1` elements (3) `next[letter]-'A'` may be negative (4) next[letter]-'A' may be above the limit. Run with a memory profiler to see what's going on.

Comment: Or just use some debug assertions/builds that will cry on out-of-bounds accesses.

Comment: My confusion is that the code is running fine: it's only crying foul during destruction!

Here's the full listing of lexicon... http://pastebin.com/Me4AcwXx

Comment: @williamstome That's a wrong impression: code with undefined behavior often appears to be running "fine", except it's actually not fine at all: a slight change in inputs leads to random crashes, different runs on the same inputs produce different results, etc.

Comment: sorry, by fine I meant that the program doesn't complain until after it has completed.

Comment: p.s., can you tell I'm a scala guy who hasn't touched c++ in four years? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Thanks to everyone who suggestion I put in asserts (god, grad school has turned me into a TERRIBLE programmer), which led me to catch the problem: one of the words in the dictionary was "MP3" which wasn't entirely alphanumeric. I didn't realize that that kind of error would wait until deconstruction to pop up; I assumed it would cause a segfault. YIKES.

Thanks all!